# TypeError: '_SessionRequestContextManager' object is not iterable

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio

From this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/debugtalk/3d26581686b63c28227777569c02cf2c) for multiple asynchronous get requests I copied and ran the following code:

```
import asyncio  
import aiohttp

def fetch_page(url, idx):  
    url = 'https://yahoo.com'
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', url)

    if response.status == 200:
        print("data fetched successfully for: %d" % idx)
    else:
        print("data fetch failed for: %d" % idx)
        print(response.content, response.status)

def main():  
    url = 'https://yahoo.com'
    urls = [url] * 100

    coros = []
    for idx, url in enumerate(urls):
        coros.append(asyncio.Task(fetch_page(url, idx)))

    yield from asyncio.gather(*coros)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

However, I get the following errors:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession._request' was never awaited

> Unclosed client session TypeError: '_SessionRequestContextManager'

> TypeError: '_SessionRequestContextManager' object is not iterable

Comment: in tutorial you can see `"Created 3 years ago"`  - so it may be outdated. For example currently you use `await` instead of `yield from`

Comment: if you want async request then see module [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/)

Comment: if you want to use `aiohttp` then better read [official documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

In tutorial you can see `"Created 3 years ago"` - so it is simply outdated.
For example currently you use `await` instead of `yield from`.

Better read official documentation for [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/).

In [The aiohttp Request Lifecycle](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/http_request_lifecycle.html#the-aiohttp-request-lifecycle) you can see similar example with `fetch()` and `main()`:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://python.org')
        print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

And it could be with your example

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(url, idx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:

            if response.status == 200:
                print("data fetched successfully for:", idx)
                #print(await response.text(), response.status)
            else:
                print("data fetch failed for:", idx)
                print(await response.text(), response.status)

async def main():
    url = 'https://yahoo.com'
    urls = [url] * 10

    for idx, url in enumerate(urls):
        await fetch(url, idx)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

or without session

```
import asyncio  
import aiohttp

async def fetch_page(url, idx):  
    async with aiohttp.request('GET', url) as response:
    
        if response.status == 200:
            print("data fetched successfully for:", idx)
        else:
            print("data fetch failed for:", idx)
            print(response.content, response.status)

async def main():  
    url = 'https://yahoo.com'
    urls = [url] * 100

    for idx, url in enumerate(urls):
        await fetch_page(url, idx)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio  
import aiohttp
async def fetch_page(url, idx):  
    async with aiohttp.request('GET', url) as response:
    
        if response.status == 200:
            print("data fetched successfully for:", idx)
        else:
            print("data fetch failed for:", idx)
            print(response.content, response.status)

async def main():  
    url = 'https://yahoo.com'
    urls = [url] * 10
    taskList = []
    for idx, url in enumerate(urls):
        taskList.append(asyncio.Task(fetch_page(url,idx)))
    await asyncio.gather(*taskList)
    enter code here

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).